# Merging two consecutive lines into one (seeking a solution working for Windows files too)

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I'd like to merge two consecutive lines in a Windows text file using external bash environment like the one that for instance Cygwin or MobaXTerm provide.

I know there are similar questions asked and already set to solved but for some reason they don't work with my environment. Is it perhaps cos Windows is adding some invisible characters unrecognized by bash tools?

Here are the solutions from other similar questions which I already tried:

```
awk 'NR%2{a=$0;next}{print a","$0}' test.txt

grep "line"  test.txt |awk 'NR==0{prefix=$0;next} {print prefix, $0}'

sed '$!N;s/\n/,/' test.txt
```

Input I'm working with:

```
first line
second line
third line
fourth line
fifth line
sixth line
```

Expected result:

```
first line,second line
third line,fourth line
fifth line,sixth line
```

Actual result with any of the code I tried so far:

1)

```
➤ sed '$!N;s/\n/,/' test.txt

,second line

,fourth line

,sixth line
```

2)

```
➤ grep "line"  test.txt |awk 'NR==0{prefix=$0;next} {print prefix, $0}'

first line

second line

third line

 fourth line

 fifth line

 sixth line
```

Any help here will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You showed expected output but not the input that would produce that output. [edit] your question to include the sample input for that output. Wrt `Is it perhaps cos Windows is adding some invisible characters unrecognized by bash tools` - probably, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/45772525/1745001 for how to identify and handle that.

Comment: I do believe it's pretty obvious, isn't it? It's just 6 consecutive lines, ie. practically the same thing you see as my output with grep. But okay, I'll add it to the question since people seem to be missing it.

Comment: Someone has to create an input file for us to test a potential solution against. The choices are: 1) you do it, or 2) everyone trying to help you does it. `1` makes much more sense than `2`.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, I'm just saying that the input file was already there. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat -v file
first line^M
second line^M
third line^M
fourth line^M
fifth line^M
sixth line^M
```

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='\r?\n' -v OFS=',' 'NR%2{p=$0; next} {print p, $0}' file
first line,second line
third line,fourth line
fifth line,sixth line
```

With any awk:

```
$ awk -v OFS=',' '{sub(/\r$/,"")} NR%2{p=$0; next} {print p, $0}' file
first line,second line
third line,fourth line
fifth line,sixth line
```

Comment: cat -v isn't recognized by MobaXTerm but your second solution works brilliantly! Thank you very much, kind sir :)

Answer (score 1):

with GNU `sed` -

```
$: cat in
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

$: sed 'N; s/\r*\n/,/; p; d;' in # no dash-options needed
0,1
2,3
4,5
6,7
8,9
```

`N;` - add the next line to the current one
`s/\r*\n/,/;` - replace any CR's and the new line character with a comma
`p;` - print the result
`d;` - delete it so `sed` won't autoprint.

Same output with

```
$: sed -En 'N; s/\r?\n/,/; p;' in
```

that's `-E`xtended pattern matching, `-n`o autoprint.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution is to use paste:

```
cat > FILE <<EOF
first line
second line
third line
fourth line
fifth line
sixth line
```

Then:

```
▶ paste -d, - - < FILE
first line,second line
third line,fourth line
fifth line,sixth line
```

Further explanation:

- The `paste` utility concatenates the corresponding lines of given input files. If `-` is specified for any the files, STDIN is used, and it is read circularly, one line at a time, for each instance of `-`.
- The `-d,` tells paste to use `,` as the field separator, instead of the default tab character.

Comment: An alternative `paste -sd',\n' file`.

Comment: @potong, that doesn't work on my paste (BSD, Mac OS X). I guess that's a GNU version?

Answer (score 0):

here is one `awk` solution

```
awk 'NR%2==1{x=$0;next}{print x "," $0}' file
```

the output

```
first line,second line
third line,fourth line
fifth line,sixth line
```